# How can I kill a process in both Windows and Linux?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, posix, kill-process

Is there easy way to kill a process using its process ID (`pid_t` in Linux and `PROCESS_INFORMATION::dwProcessId` in Windows)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

linux: `kill(pid, SIGKILL);`

Windows: `TerminateProcess(Handle, 1)` where you get Handle from `OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessId);`

Note that both of these will simply kill the process, the target is given no chance to shut down properly. If you want to let the target get a chance to do this, use SIGHUP and then SIGTERM on linux. For windows, you could send WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_CLOSE if you have the target applications main window handle, this can be found with EnumWindows and GetWindowThreadProcessId